# yii echo CJSON::encode($dataProvider->getData()); repeat data on last page

Tags: php, yii

i use this code

```
public function actionPlacemenu() 
    {       
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $id=$_POST['x2'];


        if(!empty($id))
        {
         $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('AmakenMenu',array(
                     'criteria'=>array(
                                                'condition'=>'admin_active=1',
                                                'condition'=>'place_id=:projectId',
                                                'params'=>array(':projectId'=>"$id"),

                                )));
        $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize =1000000; 
        $dataProvider->pagination->pageVar = 'page';
        echo CJSON::encode($dataProvider->getData()); 
        }
    }
```

this code send data to Android App... when i access final page data repeated

EX:  page=10  "last page"   at page=11,12....   repeat same data

any one have solution?

Comment: It seems to be filter/condition issue. 'condition' should be used only one time in each 'criteria' to avoid overwritting it. If you want to merge both conditions I suggest you something like: 'condition'=>'admin_active=1 and place_id=:projectId'. Other option is to use $criteria->addCondition(...) (for very complex and nested conditions). I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution

```
$total=ceil($dataProvider->totalItemCount/10);
        if(isset($_GET['page']) &&  $_GET['page']>$total) 
        {
            die;
        }
```

$total   ->    show num of pages 
and 10 ->   num of records per page

Answer (score 0):

Using 'validateCurrentPage' => false works for me.

Sample structure :

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('LabOrderDetail', array(
        'criteria' => $criteria, 'pagination' => array('pageSize' => $pageSize ,'validateCurrentPage' => false)
    ));
```